# How to add different lines for facets

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have data where I look at the difference in growth between a monoculture and a mixed culture for two different species. Additionally, I made a graph to make my data clear.

I want a barplot with error bars, the whole dataset is of course bigger, but for this graph this is the `data.frame` with the means for the barplot.

```
plant           species     means
Mixed culture   Elytrigia   0.886625
Monoculture     Elytrigia   1.022667
Monoculture     Festuca     0.314375
Mixed culture   Festuca     0.078125
```

With this data I made a graph in `ggplot2`, where `plant` is on the x-axis and `means` on the y-axis, and I used a facet to divide the species.

This is my code:

```
    limits <- aes(ymax = meansS$means + eS$se, ymin=meansS$means - eS$se)
    dodge <- position_dodge(width=0.9)

    myplot <- ggplot(data=meansS, aes(x=plant, y=means, fill=plant)) + facet_grid(. ~ species) 
    myplot <- myplot + geom_bar(position=dodge) + geom_errorbar(limits, position=dodge, width=0.25)
    myplot <- myplot + scale_fill_manual(values=c("#6495ED","#FF7F50"))
    myplot <- myplot + labs(x = "Plant treatment", y = "Shoot biomass (gr)")  
    myplot <- myplot + opts(title="Plant competition")
    myplot <- myplot + opts(legend.position = "none")
    myplot <- myplot + opts(panel.grid.minor=theme_blank(), panel.grid.major=theme_blank())
```

So far it is fine. However, I want to add two different horizontal lines in the two facets. For that, I used this code:

```
    hline.data <- data.frame(z = c(0.511,0.157), species = c("Elytrigia","Festuca")) 
    myplot <- myplot + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = z), hline.data)
```

However if I do that, I get a plot were there are two extra facets, where the two horizontal lines are plotted. Instead, I want the horizontal lines to be plotted in the facets with the bars, not to make two new facets. Anyone a idea how to solve this.

I think it makes it clearer if I put the graph I create now:

[image]

Comment: Is `abline` what you're looking for ?

Comment: No I want just a horizontal line, at a given y coordinate. However the value are different for each facet, eg facet Elytrigia has a horizontal line at 0.511 and facet Festuca a horizontal line at 0.157.

Comment: May I suggest you cut and paste your data set exactly as is from the console or use `dput(means)` to give us your data.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Make sure that the variable species is identical in both datasets. If it a factor in one on them, then it must be a factor in the other too

```
library(ggplot2)
dummy1 <- expand.grid(X = factor(c("A", "B")), Y = rnorm(10))
dummy1$D <- rnorm(nrow(dummy1))
dummy2 <- data.frame(X = c("A", "B"), Z = c(1, 0))
ggplot(dummy1, aes(x = D, y = Y)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(~X) + 
    geom_hline(data = dummy2, aes(yintercept = Z))
```

[image]

```
dummy2$X <- factor(dummy2$X)
ggplot(dummy1, aes(x = D, y = Y)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(~X) + 
    geom_hline(data = dummy2, aes(yintercept = Z))
```

[image]

Comment: Oh yeah, now I remembered that there was a space behind my species name, how annoying. At least there was nothing wrong with my code

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for `geom_abline`, or did I mess something up? See my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43696806/r-ggplot-different-geom-ablines-in-facets

Comment: You need to specify the `data = dummy2` in the `geom_line`. Otherwise you will get the error  `Error: mapping must be created by aes()`.

Answer (score 1):

Another option using `geom_abline` where you specify the `intercept` as your position of the horizontal line and you have to make sure the `slope` is 0 in your aesthetics. Here is some reproducible code (slightly adjusted from @Thierry):

```r
library(ggplot2)
dummy1 <- expand.grid(X = factor(c("A", "B")), Y = rnorm(10))
dummy1$D <- rnorm(nrow(dummy1))
dummy2 <- data.frame(X = c("A", "B"), Z = c(1, 0))
ggplot(dummy1, aes(x = D, y = Y)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(~X) + 
  geom_abline(data = dummy2, aes(intercept = Z, slope = 0))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

As you can see the result is the same when using `geom_hline`.