# geom_vlines multiple vlines per plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, timeserieschart

How can I get ggplot to produce something similar like
[image: Example]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(ecp)

synthetic_control.data <- read.table("/path/synthetic_control.data.txt", quote="\"", comment.char="")
n <- 2

s <- sample(1:100, n)
idx <- c(s, 100+s, 200+s, 300+s, 400+s, 500+s)
sample2 <- synthetic_control.data[idx,]
df = as.data.frame(t(as.matrix(sample2)))

#calculate the change points
changeP <- e.divisive(as.matrix(df[1]), k=8, R = 400, alpha = 2, min.size = 3)
changeP = changeP$estimates
changeP = changeP[-c(1,length(changeP))]

changePoints = data.frame(changeP,variable=colnames(df)[1])
for(series in 2:ncol(df)){
  changeP <- e.divisive(as.matrix(df[series]), k=8, R = 400, alpha = 2, min.size = 3)
  changeP = changeP$estimates
  changeP = changeP[-c(1,length(changeP))]
  changePoints = rbind(changePoints, data.frame(changeP,variable=colnames(df)[2]))
}
```

this is the interesting part about the plot:

df$id = 1:nrow(df)
dfMelt <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = "id")
p = ggplot(dfMelt,aes(x=id,y=value))+geom_line(color = "steelblue")+ facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales = 'free_y')
p + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=changeP), data=changePoints, linetype='dashed')

So far my result is: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mysadkruo946oox/changePoint.pdf which means that there is something wrong with my array passed to the `geom_vlines`.

Could you point me in the right direction why I only get `vlines` in the first 2 plots?

Comment: if you install the R package ecp it should be possible to just copy / paste the code.

Comment: I updated the question -- the part for ecp is working now and I get some simple vlines BUT only in parts of the plots

Comment: As http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486994/how-to-add-different-lines-per-group-in-ggplot/25488083#25488083 show I would have to change the to: xintercept=variable but this results in Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(ecp)

synthetic_control.data <- read.table("/Users/geoHeil/Dropbox/6.Semester/BachelorThesis/rResearch/data/synthetic_control.data.txt", quote="\"", comment.char="")
n <- 2

s <- sample(1:100, n)
idx <- c(s, 100+s, 200+s, 300+s, 400+s, 500+s)
sample2 <- synthetic_control.data[idx,]
df = as.data.frame(t(as.matrix(sample2)))

#calculate the change points
changeP <- e.divisive(as.matrix(df[1]), k=8, R = 400, alpha = 2, min.size = 3)
changeP = changeP$estimates
changeP = changeP[-c(1,length(changeP))]

changePoints = data.frame(changeP,variable=colnames(df)[1])
for(series in 2:ncol(df)){
  changeP <- e.divisive(as.matrix(df[series]), k=8, R = 400, alpha = 2, min.size = 3)
  changeP = changeP$estimates
  changeP = changeP[-c(1,length(changeP))]
  changePoints = rbind(changePoints, data.frame(changeP,variable=colnames(df)[series]))
}

# plot
df$id = 1:nrow(df)
dfMelt <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = "id")
p = ggplot(dfMelt,aes(x=id,y=value))+geom_line(color = "steelblue")+ facet_grid(variable ~ ., scales = 'free_y')
p + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=changeP), data=changePoints, linetype='dashed', colour='darkgreen')
```

Comment: somehow the result is not what I would expect: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30834455/plot-of-change-point-detection-using-r-ecp-package-does-not-work