# Add facet_grid panel means as text and hline

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
> head(df)
  DGene JGene cdr3_len Sum
1 IGHD1 IGHJ1        0  22
2 IGHD1 IGHJ1        1  11
3 IGHD1 IGHJ1        2  16
4 IGHD1 IGHJ1        3  40
5 IGHD1 IGHJ1        4  18
6 IGHD1 IGHJ1        5  30
...
```

It is pretty simple to facet_grid.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=cdr3_len,y=Sum)) + geom_line() + xlim(c(1,42)) + facet_grid(JGene~DGene,scales="free_y")
```

and getting something that looks like.

[image]

I was wondering if anyone could help me with adding a hline to the mean of each grid. Or possibly how to print the mean of each grid in the top right corner.

Thanks,

Edit - 
[Full link to dataframe](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2wbipiv1uycurlt/Dgene_jgenedistro.txt?dl=0)

Comment: possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846295/how-to-add-different-lines-for-facets

Comment: The trouble is precomputing the means like they do.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a way to add both text and a vertical line for the mean of `cdr3_len` by pre-computing the desired values (per @jwillis0720's comment):

First, calculate the mean of `cdr3_len` for each panel and then `left_join` that data frame to a second data frame that calculates the appropriate y-value for placing the text on each panel (because the appropriate y-value varies only by level of `JGene`).

```
library(dplyr) 

meanData = df %>% group_by(JGene, DGene) %>%
  summarise(meanCDR = sum(Sum*cdr3_len)/sum(Sum)) %>%
  left_join(df %>% group_by(JGene) %>%
              summarise(ypos = 0.9*max(Sum)))
```

Now for the plot:

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=cdr3_len, y=Sum)) +
  geom_vline(data=meanData, aes(xintercept=meanCDR), colour="red", lty=3) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(data=meanData, 
            aes(label=round(meanCDR,1), x=40, y=ypos), colour="red",
            hjust=1) +
  xlim(c(1,42)) + 
  facet_grid(JGene~DGene,scales="free_y")
```

[image]

Comment: So close! I do need cdr3_len, but the Sum are counts of each length. So I need the meanSum to be the mean length. The function. cdr3_len*Sum/sum(Sum), but I can't quite figure out that function.

Comment: Something like `meanData = df %>% group_by(JGene, DGene) %>%
  summarise(meanSum = Sum*cdr3_len/sum(Sum)) %>%
  left_join(df %>% group_by(JGene) %>%
              summarise(ypos = 0.9*max((Sum*cdr3_len)/sum(Sum))))`

Comment: I had a feeling that's what you wanted, but you said `hline` in your question, so I went with that. See updated code. You don't need to change the calculation of `ypos`, because that's calculated based on the maximum value of `Sum` for each level of `JGene`.