# R ggplot: Different geom_ablines in facets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to draw two different [`geom_abline`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_abline.html)s in my two facets. Which seem to be working differently to the `geom_hline` - which is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846295/how-to-add-different-lines-for-facets).

While

```
library(ggplot2)
dummy1 <- expand.grid(X = factor(c("A", "B")), Y = rnorm(10))
dummy1$D <- rnorm(nrow(dummy1))
dummy2 <- data.frame(X = c("A", "B"), Z = c(1, 0))
ggplot(dummy1, aes(x = D, y = Y)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(~X) + 
    geom_hline(data = dummy2, aes(yintercept = Z))
```

.. works, this:

```
library(ggplot2)
dummy1 <- expand.grid(X = factor(c("A", "B")), Y = rnorm(10))
dummy1$D <- rnorm(nrow(dummy1))
dummy2 <- data.frame(X = c("A", "B"), Z = c(1, 0))
ggplot(dummy1, aes(x = D, y = Y)) + geom_point() + facet_grid(~X) + 
   geom_abline(data = dummy2, aes(yintercept = Z), slope = 1)
```

does not:

[image: abline using facets]

Y-intercept is not affected.

Comment: `geom_abline(data = dummy2, aes(intercept = Z, slope = 1))`

Comment: thanks mate ... I should get some coffee...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For `geom_abline` you need `intercept` and not `yintercept`. Furthermore, you need to map both values inside `aes`, otherwise setting `slope` overrides what you set with `aes`. This works:

```r
library(ggplot2)
dummy1 <- expand.grid(X = factor(c("A", "B")), Y = rnorm(10))
dummy1$D <- rnorm(nrow(dummy1))
dummy2 <- data.frame(X = c("A", "B"), Z = c(1, 0))

ggplot(dummy1, aes(x = D, y = Y)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(~X) + 
  geom_abline(data = dummy2, aes(intercept = Z, slope = 1))
```