# facet_wrap add geom_hline

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-wrap

I have the following code for my ggplot - the facet_wrap function draws out 20 plots on the page for each Name and there are 5 Pcode along the x-axis. I would like to calculate the average TE.Contr for each Name and plot that value as a horizontal line on each of the plots (which are split out by Facet_wrap). Currently my codes plots the average of ALL TE.Contr. values instead of the average TE.Contr. of the specific Name.

```
T<-ggplot(data = UKWinners, aes(x = Pcode, y = TE.Contr., color =  Manager)) + geom_point(size =3.5)+ geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(TE.Contr.)))
T<-T + facet_wrap(~ Name, ncol = 5)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846295/how-to-add-different-lines-for-facets

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Minimal example using `mtcars` - you have to create a data frame with mean for each `gear` (in your case it's `Name`).

```
library(tidyverse)
dMean <- mtcars %>%
    group_by(gear) %>%
    summarise(MN = mean(cyl))
ggplot(mtcars) +
    geom_point(aes(mpg, cyl)) +
    geom_hline(data = dMean, aes(yintercept = MN)) +
    facet_wrap(~ gear)
```

For your case this should work:

```
library(tidyverse)
dMean <- UKWinners %>%
    group_by(Name) %>%
    summarise(MN = mean(TE.Contr.))
ggplot(UKWinners) +
    geom_point(aes(Pcode, TE.Contr.)) +
    geom_hline(data = dMean, aes(yintercept = MN)) +
    facet_wrap(~ Name)
```

Answer (score 9):

You could also create your own stat to calculate the line for you. Adapting the example from the [extending ggplot2 guide](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggplot2/vignettes/extending-ggplot2.html) You can make

```
StatMeanLine <- ggproto("StatMeanLine", Stat,
  compute_group = function(data, scales) {
    transform(data, yintercept=mean(y))
  },
  required_aes = c("x", "y")
)

stat_mean_line <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL, geom = "hline",
                       position = "identity", na.rm = FALSE, show.legend = NA, 
                       inherit.aes = TRUE, ...) {
  layer(
    stat = StatMeanLine, data = data, mapping = mapping, geom = geom, 
    position = position, show.legend = show.legend, inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = list(na.rm = na.rm, ...)
  )
}
```

Then you could use it like

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, cyl)) +
  stat_mean_line(color="red") +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ gear)
```

[image]