# Different `geom_hline()` for each facet of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

[image: facet]

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(year ~ fl) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(mpg$hwy))
```

I want each `geom_hline()` in the facet shown above to be the mean of the points that are only contained within that facet. I would think that I could do it with something like (below). But that doesn't work. I'm close, right?

```
library(tidyverse)
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(year ~ fl) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = mean(mpg %>% group_by(year, fl)$hwy))
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have the value you wish to use for each facet as a column in the data frame, and that value is unique within each facet, then you can use geom_hline(aes(yintercept=column)), which will then plot a horizontal line for each of the facets

Comment: Thanks, an expansion on this can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46327431/ggplot2-and-facet-wrap-add-geom-hline