# Display a summary line per facet rather than overall

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to do something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11846295/how-to-add-different-lines-for-facets), but hoping to do it in a single block rather than caching values separately.

I am creating a chart similar to this:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column("carmodel") %>%
  mutate(brand = substr(carmodel, 1, 4)) %>%
  group_by(brand, cyl) %>%
  summarize(avgmpg = mean(mpg)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=brand, y = avgmpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(cyl~., scales = "free_y") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Grouping by one of the fields, and then charting a calculated `summarize()` value on the result, using facets to place similar observations together.  What I would like to do is add a line in each facet showing the mean of the observations for that facet.  I have tried adding `geom_hline(aes(yintercept = mean(avgmpg)))` to the definition, but it returns the mean for the entire dataset, not the observations in the facet:

[image]

What I'm after is more like this.  (The lines here are drawn with an image editor.)

[image]

Is this possible?

Comment: look towards the end of the examples here: https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_abline.html  it shows exactly how to calculate facet-specific means.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because you said you wanted to do it in one block, note that among the many uses of `.` you can use it in geoms to refer to the original data argument to `ggplot()`. So here you can do an additional summarise to get the values for `geom_vline`. I also just reversed the aesthetics in `geom_point` instead of using `coord_flip`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column("carmodel") %>%
  mutate(brand = substr(carmodel, 1, 4)) %>%
  group_by(brand, cyl) %>%
  summarize(avgmpg = mean(mpg)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y=brand, x = avgmpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_vline(
    data = . %>%
      group_by(cyl) %>%
      summarise(line = mean(avgmpg)),
    mapping = aes(xintercept = line)
    ) +
  facet_grid(cyl~., scales = "free_y")
```

[image]

Created on 2018-06-21 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).