# Adding median lines to faceted ggplots

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I am working on a plot where I am comparing values (y variable) for two groups (x variables) across numerous sites (facets). Using ggplot, I have been able to facet the plot based on the faceting variable (in this case site) and display my data, but have been unable to determine how to add a line segment to each group that indicates the median value for that group.

Reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- diamonds %>%
  filter(color == "D" | color == "E") %>%
  filter(carat > 1)

p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x = color, y=carat, fill=color)) +
  geom_jitter(shape = 21, col="black") +
  facet_wrap(~ cut, ncol = 5)

p
```

Outputs:

[image: Current output]

What I would like to output would be something like the following (note, lines not actually drawn at medians):

[image: Example of desired output]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display a summary line per facet rather than overall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50980134/display-a-summary-line-per-facet-rather-than-overall)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm looking for a median value for each color at each cut, where as this example would only display a single median across the cut.

Comment: Can you use the information in the answer to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50980134/display-a-summary-line-per-facet-rather-than-overall) to figure out the answer to your own question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
p + stat_summary(fun = "median", fun.min = "median", fun.max= "median", size= 0.3, geom = "crossbar")
```

See here
[ggplot2: add line for average per group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244157/ggplot2-add-line-for-average-per-group)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following: Create a seperate dataframe, where you summarise by group and compute the median within each group. After that you can add `geom_hline()` to your plot with `yintercept` aesthetic correctly specified:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- diamonds %>%
  filter(color == "D" | color == "E") %>%
  filter(carat > 1)

df_median <- df %>% group_by(cut) %>%
  summarise(median_carat = median(carat))


p <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x = color, y=carat, fill=color)) +
  geom_jitter(shape = 21, col="black") +
  geom_hline(data = df_median, aes(yintercept = median_carat), size = 2, color = "red")+
  facet_wrap(~ cut, ncol = 5)
```

[image]

Comment: In this example, I would like a median line for each color at each cut and not a median across both colors with the same cut.