# How to add horizontal lines in different facets for 2x2 arrangements using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, geom-hline

I have a database that was plotted and separated by facets. The facets of the first row (row `a`) need a horizontal line at 0.5, while the facets of the second row (row `b`) need a line at 1. I have already partially achieved my goal following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11847210/7769755). However, the horizontal lines at 0.5 and 1 appear in all facets.

```
library(ggplot2)

#Data
values <- c(0.4, 0.6, 0.9, 1.1)
Column <- c("UW", "LW", "UW", "LW")
Row <- c("a", "a", "b", "b")
DF <- data.frame(Row, Column, values)
DF$Column <- factor(DF$Column,
                 levels = c("UW", "LW"))
DF$Row <- factor(DF$Row,
                 levels = c("a", "b"))

#Auxiliar DF
Target <- c("a", "b")
Lines <- c(0.5, 1)
Lines_in_plot <- data.frame(Target, Lines)
Lines_in_plot$Target <- factor(Lines_in_plot$Target)

#Plot
ggplot(data = DF, aes(y = values)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_grid(Row~Column,
             scales = "free") +
  geom_hline(data = Lines_in_plot,
             yintercept = Lines,
             linetype = "dashed",
             color = "red")
```

This MWE runs but displays the following warning message:

```
geom_hline(): Ignoring `data` because `yintercept` was provided.
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if you reduce the data=Lines_in_plot part from geom_hline

Comment: That fixes the error but not the split line...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the intercept to show up in specific panels, you'll need to have the `Row` referred to in `facet_grid` available as a variable inside `Lines_in_plot`. You'll also want to put `yintercept` inside `aes` so that ggplot knows to refer to the `Lines_in_plot` data for that `yintercept`.

```
...
#Auxiliar DF
Row <- c("a", "b")
Lines <- c(0.5, 1)
Lines_in_plot <- data.frame(Row, Lines)
Lines_in_plot$Row <- factor(Lines_in_plot$Target)

#Plot
ggplot(data = DF, aes(y = values)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_grid(Row~Column,
             scales = "free") +
  geom_hline(data = Lines_in_plot,
             aes(yintercept = Lines),
             linetype = "dashed",
             color = "red")
```

[image]

Comment: Ah! @Jon Spring has the same solution as me but types faster!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution:

```
library(ggplot2)

#Data
values <- c(0.4, 0.6, 0.9, 1.1)
Column <- c("UW", "LW", "UW", "LW")
Row <- c("a", "a", "b", "b")
DF <- data.frame(Row, Column, values)
DF$Column <- factor(DF$Column,
                 levels = c("UW", "LW"))
DF$Row <- factor(DF$Row,
                 levels = c("a", "b"))

#Auxiliar DF
Row <- c("a", "b")
Lines <- c(0.5, 1)
Lines_in_plot <- data.frame(Row, Lines)
Lines_in_plot$Row <- factor(Lines_in_plot$Row)

#Plot
ggplot(data = DF, aes(y = values)) +
  geom_bar() +
  facet_grid(Row~Column,
             scales = "free") +
  geom_hline(data = Lines_in_plot,
             aes(yintercept = Lines),
             linetype = "dashed",
             color = "red")
```

Two changes:

1. Move y-intercept into the aesthetic
2. Rename target to Row to match the Facet so it knows what to do with them